# Unexplained syntax error

Tags: reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am running into a syntax error that I simply cannot explain.

Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Button extends Component{
  handleClick = () => {
    this.props.onClickFunction(this.props.incrementValue)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
        +{this.props.incrementValue}
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

Error Message - Unexpected token (4:14):

```
  2 |
  3 | class Button extends Component{
> 4 |   handleClick = () => {
    |               ^
  5 |     this.props.onClickFunction(this.props.incrementValue)
  6 |   }
  7 |
```

I had this code working before, but I wanted to experiment with webpack and since those changes, I am receiving this error.  To my understanding, this is a new syntax introduced in es2015.  I believe I have everything properly configured:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.17.1",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta.2",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-fontawesome": "^1.6.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.17",
    "reactstrap": "^5.0.0-alpha.4",
    "webpack": "~3.9.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.5"
  }

module.exports = {
    entry: "./index.js",
    output:{
        filename:"public/bundle.js"
    },
    module:{
        loaders:[
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query:{
                    presets:['react', 'es2015']
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

My first thought was, maybe my configuration for es2015 is incorrect.  But I tried using the normal function syntax and still received the following error:

```
  2 |
  3 | class Button extends Component{
> 4 |   handleClick = function(){
    |               ^
  5 |     this.props.onClickFunction(this.props.incrementValue)
  6 |   }
  7 |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install [babel-preset-stage-0](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-0/) as a dev dependency like this :

`npm install --save-dev babel-preset-stage-0`

and preferably as mentioned in the [documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-0/) you need to add it to the `.babelrc` file , (you can create a `.babelrc` file in the root directory same place where `webpack.config.js` is ) and add like this :

```
    {"presets":["react", "es2015", "stage-0"]}
```

Or if you prefer inside `webpack.config.js` as you are using , in your query object you can do :

```
  query: {presets:["react", "es2015", "stage-0"]}
```

Comment: I think that might have done the trick!  I need to iron out some other issues, before I can get it to compile.  I will let you know asap.

Comment: thats fine , any problem let me know :)

Comment: That did it! Thanks!

Comment: glad to help you out :)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add the [transform-class-properties plugin](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/)
And add it to the configuration of babel:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "transform-class-properties"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I made the changes you suggested, but I now get a "Missing class properties transform." error on the same line.

Comment: do you use webapck and have another configuration for babel in your webpack loaders?

Comment: The only configuration I have is the one I posted in the question.

Comment: if you are using a `.babelrc` file then you don't need `query` part in your webpack loader. if you don't have a `.babelrc` file then add `'stage-0'` preset to the end of the array in your babel query property (in webpack)