# Problems getting webpack to call babel to transpile JSX in simple react.js setup.

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I've previously used react.js a bit for some of my own components in some simple web pages, importing from a CDN, avoiding JSX, and using ES6 without any transformation.  Now I'm trying to figure out the larger tool-set around react, using webpack and babel.  Node and npm are also new to me.

I'm having a heck of a time figuring out why babel is not getting called to transpile my JSX in index.js.  I had things working with just webpack, just trying to do a console.log message called from the resulting bundle.js, and that worked fine (before I tried to add react, babel, JSX or other dependencies).
I tried putting the babel configuration presets into a babelrc.js file at the project root instead of in the webpack.config.js loader, but that didn't seem to make any difference.  I've looked at a bunch of bare-bones tutorials, but they all seem to do things slightly different, making it very hard to figure out exactly what devDependencies I need (i.e., babel-cli, or babel, or babel-loader, etc.) and the I'm not sure if I've ended up with some version-incompatibilities or something.

I do get the following npm warnings when acquiring pacakges:

> npm WARN engine webpack@2.7.0: wanted: {"node":">=4.3.0 <5.0.0 ||
>
> > =5.10"} current: {"node":"5.4.1","npm":"3.3.4"})  npm WARN deprecated babel-preset-es2015@6.14.0:   Thanks for using Babel: we recommend
> >     using babel-preset-env now: please read babeljs.io/env to update!
> >     npm WARN install Couldn't install optional dependency: Unsupported 
> >     npm WARN engine enhanced-resolve@3.4.1: wanted: {"node":">=4.3.0
> >     <5.0.0 ||
> >     =5.10"} (current: {"node":"5.4.1","npm":"3.3.4"})  npm WARN engine loader-runner@2.3.0: wanted: {"node":">=4.3.0 <5.0.0 || >=5.10"}
> >     (current: {"node":"5.4.1","npm":"3.3.4"})

I haven't tried to change my node version, in case that might cause compatibility issues with my development environment (Windows 10/VS2017).

The npm log contains an error message that includes the following, which makes me think that babel is not getting called to do the transformation:

> ERROR in ./index.js Module parse failed:
>   C:\Users\Paul\source\WebSites\MinimalReact\index.js Unexpected token
>   (8:15) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type. |
>   export class MySpan extends React.Component { |     render() { |
>   return Hello!;  |     } | };

Environment:
IDE: Visual Studio 2017 CE,
node v5.4.1,
npm v3.3.4,

package.json:

```
{
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "name": "test_react",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^2.5.1",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.2",
    "babel-cli": "6.14.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.11.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.14.0",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2"
  },
  "scripts": { "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js" }
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```
"use strict";

module.exports = {
    entry: "./index.js",
    output: {
        filename: "./bundle.js",
        libraryTarget: "var",
        library: "MyModule"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test:"/\.js$/",
                exclude: "/node_modules/",
                loader: "babel-loader",
                query: {
                    presets:["es2015", "react"]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

index.js:

```
"use strict";

import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class MySpan extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <span>Hello!</span>; 
    }
};


function showContent() {
    var div = document.getElementById("display");
    ReactDOM.render(<MySpan/>, div);
};

export { MySpan, showContent};
```

[image: Project Structure]

Comment: Not sure if this would be any different, but have you tried the same configuration with a .babelrc file instead of in the loader config?

Comment: Have you tried adding `stage-0` in your `query` Object , You can find detailed answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47613161/unexplained-syntax-error-react-jsx/47613371#47613371

Comment: @djfdev - yeah, I tried pulling the babel presets out into a babelrc.js file instead, but that didn't change anything.  But is it supposed to be "babelrc.js" or "[filename].babelrc"?  I tried the former - maybe I got that wrong.  At any rate, it seems like it 'should' work in the loader config based on some of the examples I saw.

Comment: @Aaqib - Thanks for the suggestion.  I just tried adding stage-0, but that didn't help.  I don't think I should need that, anyway, since I'm not trying to do anything too advanced in my javascript.

Comment: It should be just `.babelrc` (dotfile) ... but agreed if your config isn't working that probably won't change things.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, realized the issue. Your `test` and `exclude` values should be regexes, not strings. Remove the outer quotes to solve the problem.

```
module: {
  loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      query: {
        presets: ['es2015', 'react']
      }
    }
  ]
}
```